# UITextView show caret when editing disabled?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextview, editing

Is it possible to configure `UITextView` (not `UITextField`) so, that it shows the caret when editing is disabled ? In addition it would be nice if the user could position the caret in the `UITextView` (also being disabled).

Any thoughts ?

Comment: where in the textView do you want to show caret?

Comment: You can enable editing, but allow no changes in delegate, and show small (1p height) view as custom keyboard.

Comment: at a certain position of the text, particular at textView.selectedRange

Comment: @MichaelV: When put this into my showKeyboard function: textView.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)); textView.reloadInputViews(); it still shows a gray bar at the bottom on iPad. It does not display a keyboard but clutters that part of the screen anyway, which I don't want it to...

Comment: what if you used just:  `textView.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)`?

Comment: on iPHone it works, on iPad still that gray bar with 3 buttons on the left occurs.